# Android Studio gradle build OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After a couple of builds that runs between 1-2 minutes Gradle just keeps running forever (have tried to wait for 30 minutes) and the only solution I have is to force close Android Studio and restart. Then I can build again, but after some time, Gradle gets stuck again. And then I can repeat the flow. 
When I open Activity Monitor it looks like this: [image]

And here are some of my gradle settings:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1" 
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4G"
}
productFlavors {
    production {
        dimension "prod"
    }
    development {
        minSdkVersion 21
        resConfigs("en", "xxhdpi")
        aaptOptions {
            cruncherEnabled = false
        }

        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        dimension "prod"
    }
}
```

gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

And my gradle setup

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta5'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

}
}
```

after 25 minutes I get this message (Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space):
[image]

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace in gradlew:

```
GRADLE_OPTS="$GRADLE_OPTS \"-Xdock:name=$APP_NAME\" \"-Xdock:icon=$APP_HOME/media/gradle.icns\""
```

by

```
GRADLE_OPTS="$GRADLE_OPTS \"-Xdock:name=$APP_NAME\" \"-Xdock:icon=$APP_HOME/media/gradle.icns\" \"-Xmx1024m\" \"-Xms256m\" \"-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m\""
```

Using jvmargs your are specifying memory for the task or JVM only. But for your error you should provide memory to Gradle for your case which should be done by specifying in GRADLE_OPTS environment variable.

```
jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

is totally different from

```
GRADLE_OPTS="$GRADLE_OPTS \"-Xmx1024m\" \"-Xms256m\" \"-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m\""
```

You can find your project's gradlew in Project View on left pane inside gradle directory

Source : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/BY3GEIVGumU/ogYYDaWf-8gJ

Comment: isn't that the same as the lines I have in my gradle.properties?

Comment: you have -XX:MaxPermSize=512m but it should be greater for your case. I have suggested -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

Comment: it did not help